# Instagram Issue of Redirect URI

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram, instagram-api

I am using https://github.com/crino/instagram-ios-sdk for instagram integration. 
I am using previously redirect_uri "igc7d978e285674a7f9a409d3520f4c780://authorize" it is working fine. I need to update some thing and redirect_uri float an error

I add https:// in redirect_uri and update that in app it give error in safari "Safari cannot open the page". What could be the issue
url scheme is defined in plist.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation needs to be changed. Use UIWebView to achieve the functionality.

The error in above is that it adds https: or http to redirect uri , which is not the right format for redirection in iOS URL scheme that why it say Page not found.